# DOM like API for working with XQuery in Java

Tags: java, xquery

is there some open source Java API (ideally not GPL) for creating an object model from an XQuery string?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's an extremely fast and powerful implementation in Saxon: http://www.saxonica.com/index.html

I've used it a number of times in production code and it is very good.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.gnu.org/software/qexo/

HTH

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/xqpretty/
is an ANTLR based implementation with Apache 2.0 license

It's not quite an object model, but produces a full AST.